# Where can I get this nice phpMyadmin features for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, rockmongo

In phpmyadmin

Say I browse a table, or do anything.

I will be told the actual sql command that I should run to execute the query.

Say I want to do a query and then I want to do something else similar. I can just run some query. Copy the SQL command, modify it, and move on. This is obviously less error prone than writing queries from scratch, see that it doesn't work, and not knowing what's wrong.

In rockmongo I don't have that feature.

Say I want to search for certain record. Then I want to modify the search with additional search. I can't do that.

So what other software to access mongodb that give that feature?

Another related feature is a feature to run any sql command I wish in phpmyadmin.

I do not have that feature in mongodb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically you don't have this feature in MySQL either - PHPMyAdmin is a third part tool just like rockmongo, but basically rockmongo does not have the features you want.  I am sure there are features people would like in PHPMyAdmin too that are not there yet.  When that happens you basically have 3 options:

1. Request the feature from the people running the project
2. Write it yourself (if the current tool is open source you could fork and extend etc.)
3. Use another tool that does have the feature you want

The effectiveness of 1 and 2 will depend on the feature you want, how easy it is to implement, what your skills are, how active the project is etc.

For number 3, there are other options for a GUI interface to MongoDB.  MongoVUE seems to have the view option you want, for example - however it is Windows based:

http://www.mongovue.com/features/

There are others too, MongoHub, PHPMoAdmin etc. - you can find them listed here:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Admin+UIs

There is a comparison of several of the UIs (and more in the comments on this blog post also):

http://timgourley.com/2010/03/16/tuesday-night-tech-mongodb-ui-edition.html

Finally, you should also consider [MongoHQ](https://www.mongohq.com/home) and [MongoLab](https://mongolab.com/home) as potential solutions, I know that HQ at least will let you add your own databases, and they both provide excellent admin interfaces for MongoDB.

Comment: I am aware of all these. I am asking if others have had experience with it so I do not have to try them one by one.

Comment: you might want to be more specific though - do you want other features that are in rockmongo, do you want it to be browser based or not, do you want to run it on Linux or Windows etc.  There is even a blog post that compares some of them on the linked page.  That plus things like the features list should give you the information you need.

Comment: where is the blog post?

Comment: it's literally the second link on the Admin UIs page

Comment: please add the link and I'll select this as the answer

Comment: done, also added links to MongoHQ and MongoLab - it occurred to me that they have awesome interfaces and might be more like what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

You can try this GUI tool for MongoDB([MongoBooster](http://mongobooster.com)) if you still need this feature. 
[image]

At the right bottom, that's a (show log) icon, you can view the real query run at the background. It's also have plenty of code templates in the editor to use and learn.
[image]

Disclaimer: I‘m the co-creator of this app.

Answer (score -1):

I think I should clarify Adam's answer.

Mongovue support the exact feature I want. It's called Learnshell. I'll update my answer to include other things I tried.